# Как посчитать количество уникальных слов?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки, динамические-массивы

есть задача подсчитать количество уникальных слов в тексте и сохранить их в вектор (составить словарь), но с ограничением, что слова между собой нельзя сравнивать. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Нельзя сравнивать **явно**? Используйте `set`.

Comment: хм, нельзя сравнивать слова? Предполагаю, что вам необходима хэш таблица для решения этой задачи. Тобишь находите хэш значение от какого-либо слова и по этому ключу ложите в таблицу ваше слово (сдесь не особо имеет значение есть ли там уже что-то или нет). Таким образом вы выполните это условий. В stl уже есть контейнеры `unorder*` которые работают именно через хэш функции

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Никакой реальный хеш не сможет гарантировать отсутствие коллизий...

Comment: @Harry никто и не спорит, но, думаю, что раз речь идет о тексте (а в языках ограниченное и относительно небольшое количество слов), то это не будет проблемой.

Answer (score 2):

Написал небольшую программу, которая выводит число уникальных слов и сами слова. Использует [std::unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) который не сравнивает слова на равенство, а определяет уникальность вычислением [хеш функции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) от слов, плюс изредка сравнивает на равенство при совпадении хеша для перестраховки.

Такой алгоритм должен работать быстро для больших данных и его время выполнения растёт линейно с ростом размера текста.

Для разбиения текста на слова используется модуль [std::regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/regex), т.е. регулярные выражения, регулярное выражение у меня определяет разделитель слов, другими словами знаки пунктуации и пробелы, отредактируйте `sepre` выражение чтобы добавить новые знаки разделения.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##VVC7boQwEOz5ij0iRRAeUlqOo06VIm2IEIf3kBWwib0Wpzy@ndimON823p2dmR15WJZimHoxbtsDF8NkGEKtSXExNtENUTjiNQS4tCTs5xAzQiqGClmnkZoo4oJg7rlIUviJwJYmVlW7ORBeCU4Qv@A0yRxWqSZ22B/oR6sq4@NNdGddBz6NkzAdUH1U0LgoTN7i5L3VeVu2h7b4yNI4DYjaMzuSnyg6Tqh6kgpck7hw5RlHlz33UUsUzPXeN4fi2fYW2u0uVpccvRQOJ49Dlrkx9XtXPmbJhUZFyZPfBVkGaQjqGuJXM5@ti7yAEfzL4K6rIHbb3UPzb7RfamcvtdemIEZvSMIghSZ4hLXaNbcYd9dWf/LXfvTftv0D)

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

int main() {
    std::string text = "Hello, world! world again.";
    std::unordered_set<std::string> words;
    std::regex sepre(R"([\s,\.\!\-]+)");
    std::sregex_token_iterator iter(text.begin(), text.end(), sepre, -1), end;
    for (; iter != end; ++iter)
        words.insert(*iter);
    std::cout << "Number of unique words: " << words.size() << std::endl;
    for (auto const & w: words)
        std::cout << w << "|";
}
```

Вывод:

```
Number of unique words: 3
again|Hello|world|
```

Предыдущий вариант решения отличается тем, что он всё таки делает сравнение строк на равенство, но редко. Т.е. если вопрос в скорости то он идеальный алгоритм. Но если задача стоит именно никогда не сравнивать строки, то предлагаю второй вариант. Он использует только равенство хешей для определения совпадения строк, т.е. строки никогда не сравнивает. Для этого я использовал [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) и [std::hash](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash). Единственный недостаток этого алгоритма в том что очень-очень редко при [коллизии хешей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) (совпадении хешей) он может пропустить некоторые слова, но эту ошибку он допускает супер редко (раз на триллион слов на 64-битных машинах, при условии что компилятор реализовал качественную хеш функцию), так что можно считать что алгоритм идеальный в практических условиях.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##VVG7bsMwDNz9FYwLFHb9ALo6TuZOHbrGgaFYjCNEllw90KCPb3cleYiiReTx7khKwzxXAydiXJYnJgZuKUKrjWJi3Cd3ROGItxhg0pGQTDFmhVQUFdJ@InNcOFsxGCYF4fskYcLARJjIcvhJwB1taNOsLcHgzcAO0jfkXJbwJRWnm/UCMjpVnW7vooeGrWbf2Jsy9tt7KdWR5EL0pX1geARVRAm7gsZZYfaRZodOl13dbbrqWORpHhF1YPZGXlH0zKAiRirwQeb3qE84@jXLsFWNgvo4@JZQvbrYQavd2emybZDCZhdwKAqf5qHuT9jksE6bvYTa0T1ViKKhBmkNtC2k73Y6OTt5BivYp8XVoIHUV0Nc@xdz3@DyIHVteTQPsUbCIIU28Axzs2ru8zx0m2uNjkpD51/3R3/JsvwD)

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    std::string text = "Hello, world! world again.";
    std::unordered_map<size_t, std::string> words;
    std::hash<std::string> hasher;
    std::regex sepre(R"([\s,\.\!\-]+)");
    std::sregex_token_iterator iter(text.begin(), text.end(), sepre, -1), end;
    for (; iter != end; ++iter)
        words[hasher(*iter)] = *iter;
    std::cout << "Number of unique words: " << words.size() << std::endl;
    for (auto const & p: words)
        std::cout << p.second << "|";
}
```

Также в последнем алгоритме выше можно заметить, что используется лишняя операция и память для хранения самих слов. Если нам нужно вывести только число уникальных слов, но не нужно выводить сами уникальные слова, то алгоритм можно упростить и ускорить и сэкономить память, убрав хранение самих слов и используя [std::unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set). Также в этом финальном алгоритме можно заметить, что раз мы не храним слов вообще, то очевидно что мы их не сравниваем и даже не можем сравнить на равенство никак.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##VVCxcsMgDN39FYq74MbxXdfE8dypQ9e65yNGcbhiSEFcc@31213AQ6gWpKf3niTG63U3Kq6nZXmQelReILSOrNRTV9wRixPeckCaQEI@55jXxgq0KAaHlDfOXo8kjeaqKwqpCWYuNavgp4AQjsR@v44EwhvBEcpnVMrU8GWsEpv1AT4FVVMe7qJ/A1snv3GgLrKFy1gX7i5tNqSDiKDNKOk8cHi1yF5L9ta7um/6Tb9731ZllRFdYg5kPlAPktByMhZiwuLqzQmneFmdDmlQi5gn3xp2TyEP0Gp3Djp2SFLYHBMO220sq9SPkS5ppHZoia1Ls8dEyXcajSdoWyhf/HwKbuYMXstPj6t@D2Xsrl7xj8LHhzpJw1R1KH6LZfkD)

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    std::string text = "Hello, world! world again.";
    std::unordered_set<size_t> words;
    std::hash<std::string> hasher;
    std::regex sepre(R"([\s,\.\!\-]+)");
    std::sregex_token_iterator iter(text.begin(), text.end(), sepre, -1), end;
    for (; iter != end; ++iter)
        words.insert(hasher(*iter));
    std::cout << "Number of unique words: " << words.size() << std::endl;
}
```

**Замечание!!!** Я в коде использовал стандартные хеш-функции предоставленные в STL компилятором. На самом деле компилятор может их реализовать как стойкими к коллизиям, так и нет, стандартом это не оговаривается. От этого будет зависеть качество алгоритма. Если необходимо очень точное решение, то нужно взять SHA-512 функцию в интернете (есть много авторов GitHub кто предоставляет компактную реализацию этой функции в одно-файловой библиотеке). Если стоит вопрос скорости, то лучше взять [xxhash](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash), он необычайно быстрый и при этом имеет очень мало коллизий.

Comment: И все же, вы знаете какая именно хэш-функция ([тут написано](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) -- The actual hash functions are implementation-dependent) используется, чтобы утверждать, что коллизии происходят *`"раз на триллион слов"`*?

Comment: @avp В популярных компиляторах (MSVC, GCC, CLang) используют как раз очень сильные функции с хорошей устойчивостью к коллизиям. Т.е. там не просто сумма байт. Я смотрел реализации. Кроме того есть две возможности - либо использовать SHA-512 реализацию (простые одно-файловые реализации всюду доступны), либо можно вместо одной хеш функции использовать портфель функций, например просто добавив в начало каждой строки 5 различных фиксированных префиксов мы получаем 5 различных функций. Общую функцию мы получим как конкатенацию хешей этих 5 функций. Это сильно повысит качество общего хеша.

Comment: @avp Т.е. тут вопрос в том, насколько идеально нужно решить задачу. Если нам действительно очень точно надо решить, то просто возьмём SHA-512. А если достаточно приблизительно очень качественного решения, то моё решение подойдёт для известных хороших компиляторов с хорошей реализацией хеша.

Comment: Т.е. что именно стоит за `std::hash<std::string> hasher` (SHA-512 или Bernstein), скажем в g++ 7.5 вы не знаете? (Т.о. оценить время работы не удастся)

Comment: На практике SHA-512 для подобной задачи (64 байта для любого слова (сколько оно в среднем? байт 6, наверное)) брать в любом случае не стоит

Comment: @avp Это я утрировано сказал SHA-512, если задача под-небесно точно решить. Но конечно если просто задача практическая, как хеширование слов всего интернета, то если там десяток слов пропадёт из триллионов страниц, то никто не заметит. Т.е. это нужно узнавать у автора задачи степень точности и какие гарантии компилятора для этого нам нужны. Для скорости и большой точности достаточно бы взять [xxhash](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash). У него действительно очень мало коллизий.

Comment: @avp Если что, я добавил в конец моего ответа замечание, где указал предупреждение о возможных плохих реализациях STL хеша и способы решения этой проблемы.

Comment: вообще-то, ответ правильный (я его + отметил), просто нужно предостеречь возможных будущих читателей (что мы и сделали в комментариях). Реально же SHA-512 используют для того, чтобы большие файлы индексировать...

Answer (score 0):

Например так :)

```
string str;
getline(cin, str);

//Разделители слов
string delims = "!?. ";
//Набор уникальных слов
set<string> unique_words;
//Позиция предыдущего слова
size_t prev = 0;
//Позиция следующего слова
size_t next;
do {
    //Получаем позицию начала нового слова
    next = str.find_first_of(delims, prev);
    //Обрезаем строку добавляя слово в набор
    if(next != prev)
        unique_words.insert(str.substr(prev, next - prev));
    prev = next + 1;
} while (next != string::npos);

cout << "Кол-во уникальных слов: " << unique_words.size() << endl;
for (set<string>::iterator it = unique_words.begin(); it != unique_words.end(); ++it)
    cout << *it << endl;
```

Comment: Кстати говоря std::set как раз таки сравнивает на равенство слова, внутри своего кода, т.е. если строго делать то что просил автор вопроса, то думаю нужно std::unordered_set использовать.

Comment: std::unordered_set никогда не даёт осечки, он разделяет объекты по хешу, но если хеш совпал то для перестраховки проверяет на равенство сами объекты, т.е. равенство строк всё таки делает. Но просто он делает это редко, т.к. хеш совпадёт редко. Более того он даже весь хеш не использует а только часть младших бит. Так что думаю с точки зрения "не-сравнения-на-равенство" unordered_set идеален, сравнивает редко, и никогда не промахивается.

Comment: @Arty мы не сравниваем слова явно, и я думаю в данной задаче `unordered_set` и `set` на одном уровне. Я например в конец каждой строки могу добавлять какой нибудь один символ и уже использовать `set` т.к. я не сравниваю сами слова, а сравниваю `модифицированную` строку, как и хеши. Почему нет

Comment: @Arty "сравнивает редко" хмм. А разве это не противоречие задаче? Сравнение ведь произойдет когда нибудь

Comment: Да это противоречие задачи, но его не избежать, если нужна идеальная точность. Конечно если почти идеальная точность нужна, то нужно брать такую реализацию std::unordered_set которая только хешы считает и никогда не сравнивает сами объекты. Такое тоже можно в несколько строк реализовать если надо. Ждём когда автор уточнит это. Но пока оба set и unordered_set внутри себя делают сравнения, просто set делает их заметно больше чем unordered_set.

Comment: @Arty зная как точно работает `unordered_set` вы написали первый комментарий, где написали, что "если строго делать то что просил автор вопроса, то думаю нужно std::unordered_set использовать", а пришло все к тому, что `unordered_set` так же сравнивает, но реже. Хмм...

Comment: Да, я просто что-то сразу не подумал, что unordered_set тоже сравнивает но редко, просто мне так в голову пришло что мол он на хеше базирован и только хеш сравнивает, но позже вспомнил что он также сравнивает на равенство редко. Вообщем оба сета не подходят если строго задачу воспринять.

Comment: Кстати, можно считать что если сделать решение базированное только на хешах, то оно тоже будет идеальным для практических задач. Например берём  SHA-512 хеш. Ещё никто ни одной коллизии не нашёл, ни одного примера. Более того статистически у него может быть коллизия при количестве слов в тексте порядка 10^100, до этого порядка нереально найти коллизию. Если рассмотреть практическую задачу где у нас очень много слов, например в Google поисковике задача индексации всех веб страниц мира. Тогда при таких задачах если 1 слово на триллион потеряем, то это вообще никакой роли не сыграет.

Comment: @Arty сдесь даже не просто "одно слово на триллион", а "одно слово на триллион уникальных слов" - в условиях человеческих языков (которые составляют всето несколько тысяч - десятков тысяч уникальных слов) это можно считать невозможным